# Reapeat/until help in lua

Tags: windows, input, lua, repeat

Hello I've been trying to get this code to work, I even cheated and added in the goal to my code and its still not accepting my answer, any suggestions?

```
-- Functions...
function p() -- For user imput..
        print("Enter # and try to get the closest to it! (Valid range is 1-100)")
        local var = tonumber(io.read())
        if var == nil then
            var = 0
        end
return var
end
--Start main code..


-- Initialize the pseudo random number generator (I'm on windows...)
math.randomseed( os.time() )
math.random(); math.random(); math.random()
-- Setting goal
goal = math.random(1,100)
-- Guessing loop...
repeat
        g = p()
        print(g)
        print(goal)
until g == Goal
print("YOU GUESSED THE GOAL!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the G by a lower case g.

```
until g == goal
```